# Get text value of node based on another node text in xslt

Tags: c#, xml, pdf, xslt

I have an xml with the following example format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<EnvioDTE version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte EnvioDTE_v10.xsd">
<SetDTE ID="SetDoc">
<Referencia>
  <NroLinRef>1</NroLinRef>
  <TpoDocRef>802</TpoDocRef>
  <FolioRef>25800-220-POAMPCG</FolioRef>
  <FchRef>2021-09-30</FchRef>
  <RazonRef>25800-220- POA-MPCG00001</RazonRef>
</Referencia>
<Referencia>
  <NroLinRef>2</NroLinRef>
  <TpoDocRef>803</TpoDocRef>
  <FolioRef>EDP 03</FolioRef>
  <FchRef>2021-09-30</FchRef>
  <RazonRef />
</Referencia>
<Referencia>
  <NroLinRef>3</NroLinRef>
  <TpoDocRef>801</TpoDocRef>
  <FolioRef>176644799</FolioRef>
  <FchRef>2021-09-30</FchRef>
  <RazonRef />
</Referencia>
....bla bla bla
```

I need to get the tag text "FolioRef" only when the another tag "TpoDocRef" is equal to "801"
when i get it i need to store it and put inside a td like this,
this is what i got so far, but it doesnt show up when i create the pdf

```
<td style="font-size:12px;border-left:2px solid black">                         
         <xsl:value-of select="sii:EnvioDTE/sii:*/sii:DTE/sii:Documento/sii:Referencia[TpoDocRef='801']/sii:FolioRef"/>
    </td>
```

At the end i should be able to get "176644799"

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not create classes that represent that xml structure and deserialize your xml to those classes?

Comment: Im sorry but im recently new on this, and dont know how to achieve that

Comment: Also i forget to mention, but the tag "Referencia" may not always come inside the xml

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer. The problem was with the namespace. When I try to get the node in the `[]`, it should has the namespace as well, like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sii:EnvioDTE/sii:*/sii:DTE/sii:Documento/sii:Referencia[sii:TpoDocRef='801']/sii:FolioRef"/>
```